# Why transaction does not work? Works only first .savechanges();

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to do 2 savechanges. But first of them does not work. Ready method has simple view that says Thank you, @Viewbag.OrderName

Сontroller

```
public class Some : Controller
    {

        private AppDbContext context;
        public Some(AppDbContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }
[Httpost]
public ActionResult Buy(int? id, string Price,Order order)
        {
            if (id == null) return RedirectToAction("Index");


                using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    context.Orders.Add(order)
                    context.SaveChanges();

                    if(Price!=null)
                    {var ty=context.Phones.Where(p => 
                     p.PhoneId==id).FirstOrDefault();
                    ty.Price1=Price+150;
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    transaction.Commit();

                }
                return View("Buy");
              }
               public ActionResult Ready(int? id, string OrderName)
                {
                    ViewBag.PhoneId = id;
                    ViewBag.OrderName = OrderName;
                    return View();

                }
          }
      }
```

Startup

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:AppDb:ConnectionString"]));

            services.AddTransient<Some>();}
```

Context class

```
  public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AviaAppDbContext> options)
            : base(options) 
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
```

appsettings

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Data": {
    "AppDb": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=AppDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
```

Added view for more information
View 1

```
foreach p in Model
<form method="post">
 <td class="pricelight"><input type="radio" name="price"value="@p.PriceLight.ToString("")"/>@p.PriceLight.ToString("")</td>
        <td class="fromtabletime"><input type="radio" name="price"value="@p.PriceOk.ToString("")/>@p.PriceOk.ToString("")</td>
        <td class="totable"><input type="radio" name="price"value="@p.PriceHigh.ToString("")/>@p.PriceHigh.ToString("")</td>
         <td class="button13"><button type="submit" asp-action="Buy" asp-route-id="@p.PhoneId" asp-controller="Home">Next</button></td>
</form>
```

View 2

```
@using System.Linq;
@using System;


@model List<Searchphone>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PhoneId";
}


<h2 class="orderinformation">Order Data</h2>
<form method="post" class="formpass" asp-action="Ready" asp-controller="Some">
    <input type="hidden" id="PhoneId"value="@ViewBag.PhoneId" name="PhoneId">
    <label for="OrderSurName">Surname</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Surname" name="OrderSurName" required><br>

    <label for="OrderName">Имя</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="OrderName" required><br>
    <button type="submit" class="button7">Next</button>
</form>
```

I have checked it without Transaction. It works the same. I can not make changes in two tables,one context. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AppDbContext` doesn't have a parameterless constructor, and you are trying to invoke one in the using statement. Also, you already are injecting the `DbContext` with DI so its already initialized and ready to use. With that said you don't need to create a new instance of the context, just use the existing one that you already passed in trough DI.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! I deleted `using (var context = new AppDbContext())//error is here` But savechanges works only for first using. Why?

Comment: Well i cant tell for sure, i need to test this out. But on the other hand, having a second look at your snippet, I don't see the need of adding transactions. Maybe I'm missing the whole picture, but `SaveChanges()` when executing, executes inside of a transaction

Comment: I decided to use Transaction because I thought we cant do savechanges in two different tables in one time. For this method I use form. In this form I have button submit  `<button type="submit" asp-action="Ready" asp-controller="Some"class="button7">Next</button>`. And when I get this problem(savechanges only in one table). But if I do `<button type="submit" class="button7">Next</button>`  it works twice(one is null, one has data ) but all changes save.

Comment: You can use `SaveChanges()` to persist data to multiple tables, this includes Insert, Update and Delete. EF context serves as an UnitOfWork, which means that it tracks all changes in memory and then when you do SaveChanges it will persist all changes to the database. Also can you please include your whole code if possible

Comment: I added above more information. What is my mistake?

Comment: First put the asp-action and asp-controller in the form tag. Second i dont see a Ready method anywhere in the controller. Third i dont think this line will work `{context.Orders.Price1=Price+150;}`

Comment: It still does not do savechanges at first time. Edits above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `edit` Phones data which PhoneId equals to the id parameter, you need change 
 `context.Price1=Price+150;` to  `ty.Price1=Price+150;`

More code as follow:

```
  [Httpost]
   public ActionResult Buy(int? id, string Price,Order order)
    {
        if (id == null) return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
            using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                context.Orders.Add(order)
                context.SaveChanges();

                if(Price!=null)
                {var ty=context.Phones.Where(p => 
                 p.PhoneId==id).FirstOrDefault();
                 ty.Price1=Price+150;
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Commit();

            }
            return View("Buy");
          }
```

Comment: Thank you, I wrote it with mistake. But my main problem is still here. I get the price edit, but not  `context.Orders.Add(order)` -  if I use `<form method="post" class="formpass" asp-action="Ready" asp-controller="Some">` . But if I do <button type="submit" class="button7">Next</button> it works twice(one is null, one has data ) but all changes save.

Comment: In fact, the action corresponding to the form here is `Ready` instead of `Buy`. In the code you gave, I didn't see the relationship between these two actions. You need to tell us how you triggered `Buy` action, maybe you ignored something.

Comment: I added View 1 when I used Buy action above

Comment: From View 1 we go to View 2(action Buy) and last View 3(action Ready) just say Thank you

Comment: @Fer, Although you provided view1, but your information is still not comprehensive enough, I can not reproduce your problem. I want to confirm with you, when you debug the code to `Buy` action, whether it's three parameters have values, and what are their content?

Comment: Do you mean `Buy(int? id, string Price,Order order)`?

Comment: @Fer, Yes, you need to debug to ensure these paramters.